# Does Amazon SES support plus addressing?

Tags: amazon-ses

I successfully send many emails through Amazon SES... however a handful of them fail due to containing the plus character (plus addressing).

Here's how the emails are sent:

```php
    "Key"       => "MyKey",
    "Secret"    => "MySecret",
    "Region"    => "us-east-1",
    "Service"   => "email",
    "Host"      => "email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
    "Params"    => [
        "Action"                            => "SendEmail",
        "Destination.ToAddresses.member.1"  => "someone+testing@gmail.com",
        "Message.Subject.Data"              => urlencode("Test Message"),
        "Message.Body.Html.Data"            => urlencode("<p>Hello, this is a test.</p>"),
        "Source"                            => urlencode("sender@example.com")
```

The response from Amazon SES is:
**InvalidParameterValue**
*Local address contains control or whitespace*

I know I can strip the "+testing" from the address, but don't believe that's the right thing to do. I'm unable to find anything in Amazon's documentation that mentions support for plus addressing or how to escape the plus character.

Has anyone else solved this?

Answer (score 1):

In the AWS addresses with + are possible. The + characters are sth called VERP - Variable Envelope Return Path -> which work exactly as they are supposed to work (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/send-email-concepts-email-format.html)

Are you sure that none of the other part use some strange characters?

You can try changing the encoding to UTF-8: Here is some example for that for SES. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/send-email-raw.html

Comment: Thanks @Ajris. It's definitely the plus that causes it to fail. I've sent hundreds of thousands of successful emails, and only the handful of addresses with the plus character fail. It's not just one address, it's all that contain a plus. There are no other non-ascii characters in the addresses.

Comment: Can you send the potential library which you are using and track how are the requests encoded to SES encoded? Maybe there is an error in the library?

Comment: @TookieWookie Sadly, no.